# How to list all the articles related to a certain category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my RoR app I have a problem with listing all items of a certain category. Here is 2 models:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category

and 

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end
```

and my Category controller method :

```
  def show
    @articles = @category.articles
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In db i have relation beetween categories and articles:

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "category_id"
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "desc"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And in my article index view page have code where on link ("Category") name I want to show all articles of certain category

```
  <td>
    <% if article.category %>
      <%= link_to article.category.name, category_path %>
    <% end %>
  </td>
```

But I receive error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: @jvillian the instance variable called `@category` is defined in CategoriesController and OP adds the link in the article index view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide `id` or `category` object that responds to `id` method in order to generate the correct link:

```
<%= link_to article.category.name, category_path(article.category) %>
```

Comment: God bless you) It helped